# unable to send email error- 0xC00402C7

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to send a simple email through the following code:

```
protected void email_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
   System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msgMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
   msgMail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("veerab@orbees.com");
   msgMail.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("murthyp@orbees.com"));
   msgMail.Subject = "Request:Joing into the  myitem.Title.ToString()";
   msgMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
   string strBody = "test mail";
   msgMail.Body = strBody;
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
}
```

I have installed the SMTP server on my local machine. The folders in mail root have all the permissions.

My mails stay in the Queue folder for sometime and then they go to the Badmail folder. I am receiving the following error:

```
Unable to deliver this message because the follow error was encountered: "This message is a delivery status notification that cannot be delivered.".
```

The specific error code was 0xC00402C7.

The message sender was <>.

The message was intended for the following recipients.
  veerab@orbees.com
Please Help.
Thank you.

Comment: If it was intended to be sent to `veerab@orbees.com`, then why is that address only set in `From`?

Comment: Try opening the mail files in the queue folder and have a look at the headers and check if everything is set as required

Comment: i checked the header and everything is looking fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following [article](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/email/why-do-i-get-c00402ce/c00402c7-errors.html) should help you there.

Comment: Can you extract the relevant information from the link and include it in the answer. Don't copy the whole article and keep the attribution.

Comment: If it didn't solve the problem, then why is it checked as the answer?

Comment: Link is now broken - there is no title or any reference to it. That is why it is important to provide it.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from Way Back Machine's http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/email/why-do-i-get-c00402ce/c00402c7-errors.html Articles provided by Dimi Takis. But since the links is broken i took it out of there and posting here. (Any cold beer is fine, thank you ; ) )

**Why do I get C00402CE / C00402C7 errors?**

If using CDONTS.NewMail, you might have come across this error, from files in your badmail folder:

Unable to deliver this message because the follow error was encountered: "Error is processing file in pickup directory."

The specific error code was 0xC00402CE.

Check permissions on the mailroot folder. IUSR_MachineName, or the authenticated user(s)/group(s), needs to have write permissions on several of its subfolders.

Try running the site / application in a different application protection level. This is not a fix, obviously, but a bandaid in case the situation is dire.

Another alternative is to use CDO.Message instead (which you'll eventually have to do anyway, since CDONTS.NewMail has been deprecated -- and no longer ships with Windows XP / .NET Server). See Article #2026 for information on using CDO.Message.

If this is the error message you received:

Unable to deliver this message because the follow error was encountered: "This message is a delivery status notification that cannot be delivered.".

The specific error code was 0xC00402C7.

Check to make sure that your SMTP service is running and that your CDONTS code sets proper and valid from and to addresses. There have been several reported problems about sending mail through CDONTS when the domain is the same as the smart host, or not the same as the smart host, and these seem to always be alleviated by using CDO.Message or a third-party component, which uses an SMTP server as opposed to the local Exchange system.

Jared Tullis suggested that turning off the "Enable drop directory quota" feature in his domain's properties cleared up this problem.